# Using render() value does not update when color box open second time

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm posting value using color box from view to controller. First time it works perfectly fine but when I reopen the color box it POST the old value to the new.

This is my color box code:

```
$('#equipmentPopup').colorbox({
    ajax: true,
    width: "620px",
    height: "450px",
    href: showEquipment,
    data: {
        briefingId: $("#briefing_id").val(),
        briefingDate: $("#Briefing_scheduled_date").val(),
        briefingEndDate: $("#Briefing_scheduled_end_date").val(),
        briefingEquipments: $('#BriefingEquipments').val()
    }
});
```

This is my action code:

```
public function actionShowEquipment()
{
    $this->layout = "//layouts/popup";

    $equipmentConflicts = '';
    $briefingId = $_POST['briefingId'];
    $briefingDate = $_POST['briefingDate'];
    $briefingEndDate = isset($_POST['briefingEndDate']) ? $_POST['briefingEndDate'] : '';
    $serializeBriefingEquipments = isset($_POST['briefingEquipments']) ? $_POST['briefingEquipments'] : '';

    $equipment = CHtml::listData(Equipment::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');
    $briefingCenter = BriefingCenter::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->currentBriefingCenterId);

    if ($briefingId) {
     $briefingEquipmentArr = BriefingEquipment::model()->findAll('briefing_id = :bId', array(':bId' => $briefingId));

        if (!$briefingEquipmentArr) {
            $briefingEquipmentArr[] = new BriefingEquipment();
        }
    } else if ($serializeBriefingEquipments) {
        $serializeBriefingEquipments = unserialize($serializeBriefingEquipments);
    }

    $briefing = Briefing::model()->findByPk($briefingId);

    if (!empty($briefing->scheduled_date) && !empty($briefing->scheduled_end_date)) {
        $minDate = $briefing->scheduled_date;
        $maxDate = $briefing->scheduled_end_date;
    } else {
        $minDate = $briefingDate;
        $maxDate = $briefingEndDate;
    }

    echo $this->render('edit/equipment', array(
        'briefing' => array(
            'briefingId' => $briefingId,
            'briefingDate' => $briefingDate,
            'briefingEndDate' => $briefingEndDate,
        ),
        'minDate' => strtotime($minDate),
        'maxDate' =>  strtotime($maxDate),
        'briefingEquipmentArr' => $briefingEquipmentArr,
        'equipments' => $equipment,
        'briefingCenter' => $briefingCenter,
        'serializeBriefingEquipments' => $serializeBriefingEquipments,
        'dateFormat' => Yii::app()->user->currentBriefingCenterDateFormat,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work for me. I see there is no passed data by colorbox, so try changing `data` to this:

```
data: function() {
    return {
        briefingId: $("#briefing_id").val(),
        briefingDate: $("#Briefing_scheduled_date").val(),
        briefingEndDate: $("#Briefing_scheduled_end_date").val(),
        briefingEquipments: $('#BriefingEquipments').val()
    }
}
```

Maybe it will help.